# implicit object creation by unsigned char[] - Is it legal to reinterpret_cast to implicit object? (P0593)

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20

In the paper [P0593R6](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p0593r6.html#objects-provided-as-byte-representation), implicit object creation was introduced, which is now in the C++20 standard (and If I'm not mistaken, it's also supposed to apply retroactively to older standards).

As the paper says [here](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p0593r6.html#objects-provided-as-byte-representation), this is meant to allow code such as:

```
unique_ptr<char[]> Stream::read() {
  // ... determine data size ...
  unique_ptr<char[]> buffer(new char[N]);
  // ... copy data into buffer ...
  return buffer;
}

void process(Stream *stream) {
  unique_ptr<char[]> buffer = stream->read();
  if (buffer[0] == FOO)
    process_foo(reinterpret_cast<Foo*>(buffer.get())); // #1
  else
    process_bar(reinterpret_cast<Bar*>(buffer.get())); // #2
}
```

This is taken from
[Practical Examples](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p0593r6.html#practical-examples) section of the paper, and is also given as a motivating example [here](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p0593r6.html#objects-provided-as-byte-representation)

The point of the proposal (which is now included in the standard) is the following:
Normally, this would be UB, because objects of type `Foo` or `Bar` have never been created. The new implicit object creation defines that these objects are now implicitly created, *if* that would make the behavior defined.

My question about this code snipped is, how is the `reinterpret_cast` here sufficient to get a pointer the implicitly created object? Why is the behavior of this code not still potentially UB?

`reinterpret_cast` here does not create a pointer to an object of such type, because these objects, even if they were created, are not [*pointer-interconvertible*](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.compound#4) with the first element of `buffer`.
That means that the resulting pointer's value is still that of a pointer to the first element of the array, not to a Foo, even though its pointer type is now changed.

I suppose that using `std::launder` here might make it legal, although I am not sure, but it's not used in the proposal. Is this an oversight in the paper or am I mistaken?

For reference: I am basing this on the effects of reinterpret_cast described in these two sections:

https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.reinterpret.cast#7

https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.static.cast#14

Update:

I think another way to phrase this problem is: How can we be sure that `reinterpret_cast(&a[0])` can give us a pointer to `b`, given that `a` "provides storage for" `b`?

I have found [this](https://github-com.translate.goog/cpprefjp/site/issues/1117?_x_tr_sl=auto&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=de&_x_tr_pto=wapp#issuecomment-1441452563) (japanese-language) comment on a github issue of the japanese-language cppreference project whose author seems to have stumbled on the same issue, and noticed how it's related to [P1839](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p1839r4.pdf) which addressed the reverse-direction (getting byte representation from an object) by changing pointer-interconvertibility.

Comment: You missed this important predicate: **it knows those bytes are a valid representation of type `T`.**

Comment: That is of course relevant to the code snippet, otherwise the implicit creation would make no sense at all. However, that fact on its own should not suffice to make a reinterpret_cast point to another object, even if that object is well-defined and has a valid representation.

Comment: @273K A valid representation of an object of type T being present somewhere is not usually enough for this conversion to work, an object must also exist at this location (the proposal makes this happen) and it needs to be pointer-interconvertible.

Comment: Since you never have a pointer to a dynamically allocated **array** (just its first element), the interconvertibility rule is irrelevant.

Comment: @Davis Herring. I think you’re right about it being to the first element. I have edited the question. I believe that since both the array and its 1st element are each not convertible with the Foo, but their being convertible with the Foo would fix the apparent issue, it‘s as (ir)relevant as it would be if was a pointer to the array itself.

Comment: _Is this an oversight in the paper_ Either it is, or «many details omitted for brevity» includes `std::launder`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating an object (implicitly or not) within an array ends the lifetime of any overlapping array elements (even if the array itself provides storage for the object), per [[basic.life]/1.5](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life#1.5). The `if` condition reads the value of `buffer[0]`, which requires it to be within lifetime ([[basic.life]/7.1](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life#7.1)). Based on this, we can already conclude that no form of IOC in `Stream::read()` could have created an object at `buffer.get()`, because doing so would not "result in the program having defined behavior" ([[intro.object]/10](https://eel.is/c++draft/intro.object#10.sentence-2)).

But even ignoring that (let's assume the read is *intended* to be valid even with a `Foo`/`Bar` object at that location, per the currently non-existent 'reading object representation' rule), you are correct that `reinterpret_cast` alone is not sufficient to obtain a pointer to the implicitly created object: `new char[N]` produces a pointer to the first element of the allocated array ([[expr.new]/10](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.new#10.sentence-1)), which is not pointer-interconvertible with the desired object ([[basic.compound]/4](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.compound#4)). `std::launder` would be needed for this purpose ([[ptr.launder]](https://eel.is/c++draft/ptr.launder)).

So yes, this seems like a mistake in the paper.

In fact, the same code snippet appears as a motivating example in the follow-up paper [P2590](https://wg21.link/p2590) (section 1.2), and this time the attached explanation does mention `std::launder` (and also creates the object *after* checking the initial byte).

Comment: Thanks. Do you happen do understand this part of the linked section 1.2: "If the destination type is a trivially-copyable implicit-lifetime type, this can be accomplished by copying the storage elsewhere, using placement new of an array of byte-like type, and copying the storage back to its original location, then using std::launder to acquire a pointer to the newly-created object" ? I suppose they're saying the memcpy would then create the object implicitly, but what do they mean with the placement new? placing what into what?

Comment: I don't think placement new is needed here, since `std::memcpy` [already does](https://eel.is/c++draft/cstring.syn#3.sentence-2) IOC, but maybe it was mentioned to make the [creation](https://eel.is/c++draft/intro.object#13) of the object in the original buffer more explicit.

Comment: What should we do when we don't have std::launder before C++17?

Answer (score 1):

> My question about this code snipped is, how is the reinterpret_cast here sufficient to get a pointer the implicitly created object?

Because it *already was* a pointer to the implicitly created object.

[[intro.object]/11 tells us](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/intro.object#11.sentence-2):

> Further, after implicitly creating objects within a specified region of storage, some operations are described as producing a pointer to a suitable created object. These operations select one of the implicitly-created objects whose address is the address of the start of the region of storage, and produce a pointer value that points to that object, if that value would result in the program having defined behavior.

Did you do one of those "suitable created object" operations? [Yep](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/intro.object#13.sentence-3):

> Any implicit or explicit invocation of a function named operator new or operator new[] implicitly creates objects in the returned region of storage and returns a pointer to a suitable created object.

So `buffer.get()` already points to a `Foo*` or a `Bar*`. It may be of type `char *`, but it is also a pointer to one of those types.

Note that C++23 does kind of break this code, as it removed the `char` exemption for implicit object creation (only allowing `byte` or `unsigned char`).

Comment: If in another part of the program, I used the pointer as if it were merely a regular pointer to the first element of the array, like accessing buffer[0], what would happen then? This would not be legal if it was a pointer to a Foo. Can the pointer be a value to different objects in a sort of superposition or should every access to it now obly be made as if it was a pointer to a Foo?

Comment: Did you miss `buffer[0]`? https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/unique.ptr.runtime.observers#2 says «Returns: `get()[i]`». `buffer.get()` can't «already points to a `Foo*` or a `Bar*`» and be used as a pointer to `char` simultaneously

Comment: @LanguageLawyer: Um... why not? `char` gets special treatment; accessing an array of `char` as an array of `char` doesn't prevent later IOC on that array.

Comment: _later IOC on that array_ IOC happens when `new char[N]` is evaluated, not «later», when `reinterpret_cast` is applied. And `buffer[0] == FOO` is evaluated in between these two things. So, either `get()` returns a pointer to `char` or to `Foo`/`Bar` in both cases. And this is UB one way or another

Comment: @LanguageLawyer: "*So, either get() returns a pointer to char or to Foo/Bar in both cases.*" My point is that it returns a `Foo/Bar*`, but you can still legally access it through a `char*` because that specifically doesn't violate strict aliasing. IOC is only invoked when the access would otherwise be UB. Since assessing through a `char*` is not UB, it wouldn't be invoked.

Comment: @NicolBolas It is still technically UB because of https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.add#6 for the `+0` if the pointer is to the `Foo`/`Bar` object instead of the `char` one. And array-`new` expressions are also specified to return a pointer to the first element, not the potentially implicitly-created object.

Comment: @user17732522 _And array-`new` expressions are also specified to return a pointer to the first element, not the potentially implicitly-created object_ Always miss this ‍♂️

Comment: @user17732522 The standard says that operator new[] returns a pointer to a suitable created object, as quoted by Nicol Bolas. I'm assuming you're saying that new expressions usually take a pointer-to-storage or some language constract from the operator but return in turn a pointer the first element, so the expression does not return the correct pointer here, while the operator itself does. Correct? In that case, wouldn't it be debatable that the new expression would not itself somehow invoke UB because it never gets a pointer to the storage/array to produce a first element pointer from?

Comment: @user17732522 are new expressions explicitly specified to not return a pointer to the potentially implicitly created object or are you only referring to the fact that the quoted part of the standard mentions only new[] operator and doesn't mention new[]-expression?

Comment: @JMC Array-new expressions return a pointer to the first element of the array (of the specified type), regardless of what `operator new[]` returns, see https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.new#10.sentence-1. For non-array new-expressions it isn't written that clearly since it only says "_points to the object created_" (https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.new#10.sentence-2), when there could be multiple created objects, but I would interpret it as referring to the single complete object that is _explicitly_ created by the new-expression.

Comment: @JMC I don't see this being any problem for the new-expression. The new-expression doesn't care to what object the pointer returned by `operator new` points. It only uses its address.

Comment: @user17732522 _there could be multiple created objects_ WDYM?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer It may cause creation of subobjects and implicitly-created objects nested in array subobjects. But I guess language-wise "_the object created_" would be understood to refer to the specific object mentioned in https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.new#1.sentence-1.

Comment: @user17732522 _It may cause creation of subobjects_ I do not think they are called «created» _implicitly-created objects_ They are created by [intro.object], not [expr.new]